# From my Android Java Code example How do I add a dynamic ICON to the List View that comes from a URL and remote server?

Tags: java, android, listview, icons

I am able to have a list view with results pulled from a mysql remote database depending on an input from a user with the code below.  The last thing I need to do is add an Icon in the list view with a dynamic Icon coming from a URL for each result.  I am trying to keep it within the same activity/java file.  Does anyone know how to do this?  If so, can you please edit my code to show the results? Thanks.

'=========================================================

```
package com.packagename;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;
public class Users extends ListActivity {
InputStream is;
ArrayList<String> results = new ArrayList<String>();
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
String result = "";
String uv = "";
uv = getIntent().getExtras().getString("dated");
ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new
ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("year",uv));
try{
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://website.com/Android53D6E3B5KF83S/users.php");
httppost.setEntity(new
UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
is = entity.getContent();
Log.e("log_tag", "connection success ");
}
catch(Exception e)
{
Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection"+e.toString());
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"failed"+e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
try
{
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new
InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),8);
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
String line = null;
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) 
{
sb.append(line + "\n");
}
is.close();
result=sb.toString();
}catch(Exception e)
{
Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result"+e.toString());
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"failed"+e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
try
{
JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
for(int i=0; i<jArray.length(); i++)
{
JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
results.add((String) json_data.get("id") + " "+ json_data.get("name")+ " " + json_data.get("sex")+ " " + json_data.get("birthyear"));
}
setListAdapter(new
ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,results));
ListView lv; lv = getListView(); lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View name, int id, long resultsb) {
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), " (Selection #" + resultsb +") ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}});
}
catch(JSONException e){
Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data "+e.toString());
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"No Entries", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
}
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android Java JSON Parse With PHP MySQL Connection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8593326/android-java-json-parse-with-php-mysql-connection)

Comment: I was able to add the code to this question, how do i delete the other one?

Comment: Right below the question, you have some tags {java, android, ...}, then below that you should have link|edit|close|delete|flag - click on delete. Also, your question shows very little or no research effort. Without seeing research effort, it is very unlikely that you will get a worthwile answer. It is helpful that you show code, but that doesn't necessarily show what you've tried to do in order to get it working. Also, if you need to update the question, click on 'edit' right below the end of the question.

Comment: I have completed many tutorials, however none put all three into one: List View from PHP Mysql Json, Post Data, and Dynamic Icon depending on results.  Have you found anything like that, or learned how to do it?

Comment: check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/541966/android-how-do-i-do-a-lazy-load-of-images-in-listview/3068012#3068012

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code its working

```
public class ImageActivity extends Activity {

    private  int SIMPLE_NOTFICATION_ID ;

    public DefaultHttpClient DefaultHttpClient;


    private ImageView imageView;

    protected String url;


    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);


        imageView =(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img);
         url = "http://website.com/Android53D6E3B5KF83S/users.php";

        BitmapFactory.Options bmOptions;
        bmOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        bmOptions.inSampleSize = 1;     
        DownloadImagesTask imageLoader=new DownloadImagesTask();
        imageLoader.execute();
    }

Handler handler=new Handler(){

    private Bitmap bmp;
    private Intent notificationIntent;
    private PendingIntent pendingIntent;
    private NotificationManager mNotificationManager;
    private Notification mNotification;

    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.handleMessage(msg);
        Context mContext=getApplicationContext();
        switch(msg.what){
        case 0:InputStream inputStream = null;
        URL urls=null;
        try {
            urls = new URL(url);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        URLConnection conn=null;
        try {
            conn = urls.openConnection();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try{
            HttpURLConnection httpConn = (HttpURLConnection)conn;
            httpConn.setRequestMethod("GET");
            httpConn.connect();
            if (httpConn.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                inputStream = httpConn.getInputStream();
            }
            BitmapFactory.Options options;
            options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            options.inSampleSize = 1;
            bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream, null, options);
            inputStream.close();

        }
        catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        case 1:mNotificationManager=(NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        mNotification=new Notification(R.drawable.icon,"started",System.currentTimeMillis());
        notificationIntent= new Intent(ImageActivity.this, Notifications.class);
        pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(mContext, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
        mNotification.setLatestEventInfo(getApplicationContext()," started", " started ", pendingIntent);
        mNotificationManager.notify(1,mNotification);
        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon);                   
        break;

        case 2:mNotificationManager=(NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        mNotification=new Notification(R.drawable.icon,"ended",System.currentTimeMillis());
        notificationIntent = new Intent(ImageActivity.this, Notifications.class);
        pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(mContext, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
        mNotification.setLatestEventInfo(ImageActivity.this, "completed", " completed ", pendingIntent);
        mNotificationManager.notify(1,mNotification);
        imageView.setImageBitmap(bmp);
        break;
        }
    }
};

    public class DownloadImagesTask extends AsyncTask<ImageView, Integer, ImageView> {

        @Override
        protected ImageView doInBackground(ImageView... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
            return null;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPreExecute();
            handler.sendEmptyMessage(1);                        
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(ImageView result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            handler.sendEmptyMessage(2);
        }
        }


}
```

Define another class

```
public class Notifications extends Activity {
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //setContentView(R.layout.main);
}

}
```